# confindence intervals extend below zero in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The confidence intervals in my plot extend beyond zero making the y axis go below zero. Any way to adjust this in ggplot so the confidence intervals doesn't go below zero while keeping the y axis limits as is?
[image]

Comment: I'll get faster (and better) answers if you add some reproducible code.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the limits as are, if results can't go below zero?

Comment: Maybe you need a different model rather than a different plotting approach?  It seems like you want a model that would force the CI to have 0 as a lower limit  instead of the one you have.  As an example (and leaving out many details), if you are using a linear model (assuming normality of errors) maybe you want the log link instead of the identity link.

Answer (score 3):

Use `geom_ribbon`:

Example data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = pmax(0, 35 - 1:100 * runif(100) ))
fit <- lm(y ~ x, data=df)
pred_df <- data.frame(x=df$x, predict(fit, interval="confidence"))

ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), data=df) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=x, ymin=pmax(0,lwr), ymax=upr), alpha=0.5, data=pred_df) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min(pred_df$lwr), NA) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option for y-axis (and similarly for x-axis):

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min_y,max_y), oob=squish)
```